# Error 500 HttpURLConnection but OK in localhost

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to call an endpoint implemented in JAVA with below HttpURLConnection. if i put the path as my aplication running in localhost, everything works great.
But when this application is published into a server(Oracle Weblogic), I get the error:

> > java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: **path**
> >         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
> >         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)

This error is thrown in below block at the line with **

```
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(new Gson().toJson(debtAccountList).getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.flush();
            ***InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());***

            System.out.println(in.toString());
            in.close();
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        }
```

What makes this works in localhost but not in deployed application?

Comment: Check the weblogic logs. A 500 status means there should be a stack trace in there of what went wrong.

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is. As suggested by @KrisRice, you must check the logs where the service is deployed along with weblogic admin logs.